# Showing call tree in kcachegrind

Tags: profiling, kcachegrind

How can I use kcachegrind to get a non-graphical tree of all my function calls, in the order they were called?

There are two typical ways to look at profiling data:

- sorted by the most expensive entries
- sorted in order of execution

I'm looking for the latter. I can sort of get it with the "Call Graph" tab, but this omits some data, and it can be confusing the way it represents loops. I'd prefer a text view, like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/ronang/WindowsLiveWriter/JavascriptprofilinginIE8beta2_DF55/image_thumb_5.png))</sub>

Comment: Did you try callgrind_annotate / cachegrind_annotate?

Comment: Ancient question, but I'm wondering the same thing myself. Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's in "All Callees" tab, which is located in lower-right subarea.

Comment: I don't think so. That doesn't show all of the immediate callees. It shows just the most expensive ones, including ones at a distance greater than one. I'm looking for all the immediate callees, in the order they were executed.